# MySQL, summing certain rows from a hash table, using results from a subquery

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to sum certain rows from a hash table using two elements: a select group of IDs and a particular key.

Here's the setup:

Table 1:

```
ID  KEY      VALUE
1   name     John Doe
1   amount   10
2   name     Jane Doe
2   amount   15
3   name     Mike Lowry
3   amount   5
```

Table 2:

```
ORDERID   TYPE      TRANSACTIONID
1001      Purchase  1
1002      Donation  2
1003      Purchase  3
```

I'm trying to get a sum of all the amounts where the type is "Purchase." Here's the query I'm using:

```
SELECT SUM(Table1.value) as balance 
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Table2.TRANSACTIONID as TID FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.TYPE = "Purchase" ) as ids 
ON Table1.ID = ids.TID
WHERE Table1.key = "amount"
```

Tweaking that, I've managed to get 0 and the total of all the rows, but not just the one result. Ideas?

Comment: FYI, MySQL tables aren't hash tables, they're database tables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your query makes an *outer join* between `Table1` and `Table2`, such that all records of `Table1` are preserved irrespective of whether a matching record is found from `Table2`.  Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

You want to make an *inner join* instead:

```
SELECT SUM(VALUE)
FROM   Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.TRANSACTIONID
WHERE  Table1.KEY = 'amount' AND Table2.TYPE = 'Purchase'
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e944f/1/0).